Bipolar 2s1p Li-ion array BMS and charging
For powering my portable circuit, I need a bipolar power supply of ±2.5 V. The circuit is low-power, but requires very precise power.
For its stabilization, I am using ADM7154 regulators for positive and ADP7183 for negative power, respectively. They have a slight difference in load current (using ultralow noise regs with the same load for me is not possible), hence the same current won't be drawn from both batteries.
Two 18650 batteries are connected in series, and I need to simultaneously charge them both from USB without replacement (two TP4056-based modules with isolated ground via a transformer? DC-DC isolator? I need to avoid using switching electrical components).
Also, I am unsure about the BMS connection scheme in this case. Individually for each battery, connecting the plus of one with the minus of the other to simply have bipolar supply? Or perhaps this is incorrect, as my assumption about isolated charging might be wrong? I am just getting into using batteries, so some questions remain unclear to me.
In summary: how do I properly connect the BMS and charge bipolar 2s battery supply?
EDIT: my solution at the moment is as follows

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"Employ separate BMIs for each cell". Body Mass Index? ;-)

"Perhaps the solution could be...:" You're sinking deeper and deeper into a monster. Keep it simple. Single 7.2 V Li-ion battery. Regulate to 5 V. Regulate to 2.5 V. Invert the 5 V to -5V. Regulate that to 2.5 V.

What you have there is not a single battery with two 18650 cells. Instead, what you have is two batteries, each battery having a single cell. Therefore, you will need to treat them as two separate batteries. Each battery has:

Its own BMS (a single-cell BMS) with its own protection switch
Its own charger (a single-cell charger, isolated from the other one)

A simpler design is to use a single battery with a single cell. Then, convert the positive 3.7 V voltage from that battery into a negative voltage -3.7 V with an inverting switching regulator. Then you can charge that single battery with a TP4056-based module.

Hey Davide, thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, a switching regulator won't work for me due to the specifics of the circuit. Additionally, I also plan to use a common 5V level in addition to ±2.5V (I apologize for not mentioning this earlier).
As a result, I will still need to combine the cells into one battery. In such a case, how can protection and charging be competently implemented? Leave individual BMS and physically disconnect the load during charging? This seems like a rather suboptimal solution.

I didn't give this much thought earlier as I got caught up in figuring out the proper charging, and it slipped my mind! It's important that this 5V shares the same ground as the 2.5V. In that case, it probably necessitates using an additional cell. Or should I just increase the voltage of one of the two? Then the load will be quite different.

But, you are considering a switching regulator! You said: " with isolated ground via a transformer? DC-DC isolator?" That is a switching regulator.

" It's important that this 5V shares the same ground as the 2.5V." Sure. My suggested solution (a single battery, but using 2 cells in series) does meet that requirement.

Yes, exactly, the method I described for isolated ground involves a switching regulator. The use of which I absolutely have to avoid. That's why I don't like the solution I have at the moment.

OK, I acknowledge your decision not to use a DC-DC. Given that, do you have any issues with the core of my answer? These are two individual batteries, each requiring its own BMS and charger.

Yes, this is where I start from. But I still need to figure out how to charge them and also achieve the necessary signal levels. Perhaps then two cells can be connected in parallel for charging, and in series for bipolar flight. During operation, each of them is controlled by a separate BMS to limit discharge, and when connected in parallel, one common BMS is used for charging. As I understand it, I can charge batteries in parallel with different SOC. Also, an OpAmp is used to raise +/- 2.5V to another 5V level. What do you think, are there any flaws in this solution?

Switching between charging/use (i.e., p/s) and different BMS is planned to be done by toggle switch.

" Perhaps then two cells can be connected in parallel for charging, and in series for bipolar flight." God no! That's how fires start. KISS (Keep it Simple). "by toggle switch" No, please don't. Be safe. Please do As I said: two chargers, one for each battery. If you must use two non-isolated USB chargers, then do as you said: place an 5 V to 5 V isolated DC-DC converter on the input of one of the USB chargers,

Okay, what's the problem with charging in parallel mode and physically switching to series mode? The current during the switchover? As an example, a similar solution is proposed in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245571/bipolar-li-ion-battery-charger?rq=1 . I was planning to use a switch anyway to disconnect the cells from the main circuit during charging, even with isolation.

Also, I still don't want to use a dc dc regulator. Two isolated usb cables for each cell is difficult, as the system provides another (but already the most common) 2s1p battery with its own separate charging, etc. I don't want to have to connect three cables while charging. I'll settle for two isolated ones, one of which will be separated by a DC-DC iso (which I really don't want to do), or switching to parallel mode. If you say it's dangerous, I'll stop with the isolated, but I really want to understand why. Unfortunately I don't have enough experience with this.

I mean more or less this configuration (pages 6-7) from https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/multi-cell-lipo-charging.pdf, but in run mode, switching goes to two separate BMSs, which are then connected in series for bipolar supply. Or is such a solution safe only when SOC is identical?

I bet you $ 1 that the reason you want a +/- 2.5 V supply is because you have a sensor that produces a bipolar signal and you need to feed it into an AD converter. If so, you don't need a 2.5 V supply. What you need instead is an op-amp to convert that bipolar signal into a unipolar signal centered on +2.5 V. Better yet, power that sensor at 0 and 5 V and it will already produce a unipolar signal centered on +2.5 V; no need to convert.

No, I have a different purpose for using a bipolar signal. It's related to the use of an ADC, but discussing further circuitry deviates too much from the topic of the request. I did use unipolar power previously, but due to some peculiarities of my circuit, it brings additional issues. I simply need to have clean +/- 2.5V, +5V; the ADC board is already designed.
